# Cannot make folder read only

Tags: windows-7, permissions, cmd

Here is what happens when I make the folder read only:
[image: read only image]

It asks for admin access to it and I click ok.
But when I go back and check it again it has reverted back to read only.

the reason I am doing this is I need to be able to make a new file in the folder via cmd.
[image: reverted]

Thanks, I am using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Folders don't show their read only status in Explorer. This is by design as users will screw things up by removing read only on Windows special folders.

The file system ignores it except it resists deletion. However programs can change the attribute and then delete it, and this is what Windows Explorer does.

As the read only attribute is unused for folders (except as noted above) Windows Explorer uses it (or the system attribute) to mark a folder as special. When opening a folder for viewing it uses the presence of the read only attribute to tell it to use a different viewer from the standard folder viewer. Like the fonts folder - instead of showing files it shows installed fonts. This use is specific to Windows Explorer and there is no support to other programs for it.

As Windows Explorer doesn't want you changing the flag it uses it doesn't show if a folder is marked read only or not. It shows indeterminate. If you click the box it will change between ticked, unticked, and indeterminate. Clicking the box and changing it, it will apply to files in the folder not the folder.

Attrib shows the attributes of a folder

```
attrib "%userprofile%\documents"
```

And you can see even though read only is set you can save files to your Documents folder.

Attrib can only change an attribute if the file doesn't have hidden or system attribute also set. To change it on these you must change all three to off.

```
attrib -r -s -h "%userprofile%\documents"
```

For Help on attrib type

```
attrib /?
```